# amCharts Minimal zoom range (minimal period selector range)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I try to use [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/). I have a chart that represent dayly data. I can't make so user wouldn't be able to choose period less than 5 days (i dont want send 5 days points to chart)

Also i can attach changed event to period selector, but chart zooming and chart scroll bar have no any events and methods i could use.

I need to do so user will see message "please select range that is more than 5 days" when he tries to scroll, select period and zoom chart. And set chart zoom to 5DD.

Also i mentioned that period selector changed event, fire every time when blur event fired on inputs, i think it's not right behavior. It should fire when date changed, yep?

```
chart.periodSelector.addListener('changed', function(){ 
  alert('changed'); 
});
```

I have date picker that attached to period selector inputs (it don't permit user to select less than 5 days range), but i can only update my datepicker ranges only if user input date, i can't to do anything if he zoomed, scrolled chart. I don't see any events in your API for that.

Thanks for your help! Will wait any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use zoomed event instead.

```
chart.addListener('zoomed', function (event) {
// Your code
}
```

And now, to get the selector's start and end date, use this:
event.startDate 
event.endDate

Comment: If you still want this problem to be solved, please provide the basic example. I'll try to edit it according to your need.